# Mysql/php: Select file extension types simple query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to select all images from table. My column is file_ext and contains jpg, jpeg, mp3, avi and so on extensions.

How can i create SQL query like this?: `AND file_ext = 'jpg, jpeg'` or to select all extensions `AND file_ext = '*'` Because I do not want to write `AND file_ext = 'jpg' AND file_ext = 'jpeg' ....`

How do you guys solve problems like this? Thanks!

Comment: `file_ext in ('jpg', 'png',..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `IN` like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mycondition AND file_ext IN ('jpg','jpeg','png',....)
```

And ALso try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

Comment: solved, thanks! was using IN NOT and absolutely forgot to use only IN, stupid me.. Will mark as answer in few mins, thanks!